# quanteda::dfm_lookup(): capture found term

Tags: r, quanteda

I would like to perform the amazing `quanteda`'s `dfm_lookup()` on a dictionary but also retrieve the matches.

Consider the following example:

```
dict_ex <- dictionary(list(christmas = c("Christmas", "Santa", "holiday"),
                        opposition = c("Opposition", "reject", "notincorpus"),
                        taxglob = "tax*",
                        taxregex = "tax.+$",
                        country = c("United_States", "Sweden")))
dfmat_ex <- dfm(tokens(c("My Christmas was ruined by your opposition tax plan.",
                      "Does the United_States or Sweden have more progressive taxation?")),
             remove = stopwords("english"))

dfmat_ex
dfm_lookup(dfmat_ex, dict_ex)
```

This gives me:

```
Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 5 features (50.00% sparse) and 0 docvars.
       features
docs    christmas opposition taxglob taxregex country
  text1         1          1       1        0       0
  text2         0          0       1        0       2
```

However, since every dictionary tool also has multiple entries, I would like to know which token produced the match. (My real dictionary is rather long, so the example might seem trivial but for the real use case, it is not.)

I would like to achieve a result like this:

```
Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 5 features (50.00% sparse) and 0 docvars.
features
docs    christmas  christmas.match  opposition  opposition.match  taxglob  taxglob.match  taxregex  taxreg.match  country          country.match
text1         1          Christmas         1          Opposition      1              tax         0            NA        0                     NA
text2         0                 NA         0                  NA      1         taxation         0            NA        2  United_States, Sweden
```

Can someone help me with this? Many thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really possible for two reasons.

First, a matrix(-like) object (dfm or otherwise) cannot mix element modes, here a mixture of counts and character values.  This would be possible with a data.frame but then you lose the advantages of sparsity, and here, you would have a n x 2*V (where V = number of features) data.frame dimensions.

Second, "christmas.match" could have more than one feature/token matching it, so the character value would require a list, straining the object class even further.

A better way would be to use `kwic()` to match the tokens to the patterns formed by the dictionary.  You can do this for the keys by supplying the dictionary as `pattern()`, or unlisting the dictionary to get matches for each value.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 3.1
## Unicode version: 13.0
## ICU version: 69.1
## Parallel computing: 12 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

dict <- dictionary(list(one = c("a*", "b"), two = c("e", "f")))

toks <- tokens(c(d1 = "a b c d e f g and another"))

# where the dictionary keys are the patterns matched
kwic(toks, dict) %>%
  as.data.frame()
##   docname from to         pre keyword            post pattern
## 1      d1    1  1                   a       b c d e f     one
## 2      d1    2  2           a       b       c d e f g     one
## 3      d1    5  5     a b c d       e f g and another     two
## 4      d1    6  6   a b c d e       f   g and another     two
## 5      d1    8  8   c d e f g     and         another     one
## 6      d1    9  9 d e f g and another                     one

# where the dictionary values are the patterns matched
kwic(toks, unlist(dict)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
##   docname from to         pre keyword            post pattern
## 1      d1    1  1                   a       b c d e f      a*
## 2      d1    2  2           a       b       c d e f g       b
## 3      d1    5  5     a b c d       e f g and another       e
## 4      d1    6  6   a b c d e       f   g and another       f
## 5      d1    8  8   c d e f g     and         another      a*
## 6      d1    9  9 d e f g and another                      a*
```